Not Nullhomotopic Closed Path in $\mathbb{R^2}\setminus\{(-1, 0), (0,1), (1, 0)\}$ that becomes so for subsets of $\{(-1, 0), (0,1), (1, 0)\}$
I came across the following exercise and I  haven't been able to figure it out:
Draw a closed path $f$ of class $C^1$ in $\mathbb{R^2}\setminus\{(-1, 0), (0,1), (1, 0)\}$ such that:

$f$ is not nullhomotopic in $\mathbb{R^2}\setminus\{(-1, 0), (0,1), (1, 0)\}$,
$f$ is nullhomotopic in $\mathbb{R^2}\setminus \{(0, 1), (1, 0)\}$, $\mathbb{R^2}\setminus \{(-1, 0), (1, 0)\}$, and $\mathbb{R^2}\setminus \{(-1, 0), (0, 1)\}$.

What I have been able to figure out is that each $ x \in \{(-1, 0), (0,1), (1, 0)\}$ should have winding number $Ind(f, x) = 0$, since homotopy preserves the winding number and the winding number of any point for the constant path is zero. Because of this fact I think that there should probably be some kind of double loop around each point $x$, one loop with clockwise direction and the other with anti-clockwise direction.
I also imagine a potential solution might have some kind of symmetry of $f$ with respect to either all three points $\{(-1, 0), (0,1), (1, 0)\}$ or at the very least between $\{ (-1, 0), (1, 0)\}$.
Any insight or explanation would be greatly appreciated!

This is perhaps not the best example, but it answers the question. Consider the closed path in the following image.

To construct this path, I used the fact that the first homotopy group of $\mathbb C \setminus\{-1,i,1\}$ is the free group on three letters, call them $a$, $b$, $c$. Each letter corresponds to a non-contractible loop with winding $1$ around one of the points and $0$ around the others (in this example, $a,b,c$ go around $i,-1,1$, respectively). When we put the point back in, that corresponding letter is set to the identity element $\epsilon$ (i.e., the empty word) because we can "shrink" the loop around it. So we need to construct a nontrivial word using three letters and their inverses such that setting any one the letters to identity makes the word itself identity. One such word is
$$
a b c b^{-1} a^{-1} b a c^{-1} a^{-1} b^{-1}.
$$
It is easy to see that removing all instances of any letter and its inverses makes this word trivial.

A simpler example, suggested by @JohnHughes is to construct such a path in $\mathbb C\setminus \{-1,1\}$. In this case, the word $aba^{-1} b^{-1}$ does the job, and the resulting curve (with $a,b$ going around $-1,1$, respectively) looks like:


You're on exactly the right track. If you have a piece of wood, some nails, and a rubber band, you can play around and experiment, which may go faster than doing it on paper. It might be profitable to consider a reduced version of the question --- start with just $-1$ and $1$ removed, find an "essential" (not nullhomotopic) loop, and show that if either is added back in, your loop becomes nullhomotopic.

Nice video of Up and Atom about this: https://youtu.be/-eVd2Ugk9BU?si=Ss386NudChd1Ckvj
